# Build OpenJDK7 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: build, ubuntu-12.04, java

I have followed all recommended steps to build openJDK7 ([openJDK build example](http://gleamynode.net/articles/2296/)) on my Ubuntu 12.04 instance, but i still fail on Java hotspot compilation with given error:

```
In file included from /home/ubuntu/openjdk-build-sandbox/openJDK7/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/methodHandles.hpp:32:0,
             from /home/ubuntu/openjdk-build-sandbox/openJDK7/hotspot/src/share/vm/ci/ciMethod.hpp:33,
             from /home/ubuntu/openjdk-build-sandbox/openJDK7/hotspot/src/share/vm/code/debugInfoRec.hpp:30,
             from /home/ubuntu/openjdk-build-sandbox/openJDK7/hotspot/src/share/vm/ci/ciEnv.hpp:31,
             from /home/ubuntu/openjdk-build-sandbox/openJDK7/hotspot/src/share/vm/ci/ciUtilities.hpp:28,
             from /home/ubuntu/openjdk-build-sandbox/openJDK7/hotspot/src/share/vm/ci/ciNullObject.hpp:30,
             from /home/ubuntu/openjdk-build-sandbox/openJDK7/hotspot/src/share/vm/ci/ciConstant.hpp:29,
             from /home/ubuntu/openjdk-build-sandbox/openJDK7/hotspot/src/share/vm/precompiled.hpp:36:

/home/ubuntu/openjdk-build-sandbox/openJDK7/hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/interfaceSupport.hpp:430:0: error: "__LEAF" redefined [-Werror]
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/cdefs.h:44:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known error: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-7/+bug/935346 (includes a fix).